# solid red + solid green on bootup

Tags: boot, sd-card, noobs

Just got an SD card: 
SanDisk Ultra 32GB microSDHC UHS-I Card with Adapter, Grey/Red, Standard Packaging (SDSQUNC-032G-GN6MA) ([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B010Q57T02](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B010Q57T02))
Formatted it with SDFormatter and put NOOBs files one it.

Pi doesn't boot - solid red and solid green upon bootup.

I tried putting the Raspbian image on the card and the same problem.

Mac Utility says that the disk is fine.  What else can I try before I go get another SD Card?

Comment: May I know which particular image ?

Comment: What method did you use to write the image onto the card?

Comment: I used this one: RASPBIAN JESSIE
Based on Debian Jessie
Version:September 2015
Release date:2015-09-24
Kernel version:4.1

Comment: Here is how I wrote the image  sudo dd bs=1m if=./2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/rdisk2s1

Comment: If you are sure you've done everything correctly all you can do is try another card.  Don't bother with exactly the same brand and model.  Use something with a smaller capacity (4 or 8 GB).

Comment: ok thanks.  Yeah I will get a different card now and try it out.